# MongoDB zip achive missing ssleay32.dll when execute mongod.exe

Tags: mongodb, ssl, dll, openssl, windows-7-x64

I have used mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.0 zip archive on Windows Server 2008R2 x64 and it works well.

However, I have tried to run mongod.exe on Windows 7 x64, but it failed due to the missing ssleay32.dll. According to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17368 it missing the ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll in zip archive, which are exist in msi package.

I have tried to downloaded https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1s and let it install dll into windows system folder. And also downloaded http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ openssl-1.0.2g-x64_86-win64.zip and extracted the two dlls into ${MONGODB}\bin. But, both of them are not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: You might be able to install Shining Light's [Win32OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Or, build the library yourself according to `INSTALL.W32`.